# Do not allow to search certain words

Tags: search, exclude

I would like to delete (not allow) searches with certain keywords (eg "of", "a").

If the search is done using exactly these terms, do not return anything or redirect to 404 page ...

Thanks guys.

Comment: I know this isn't helpful, but can I ask why you want to do that?

Comment: Sure @Dominic. Some spammers tend to enter short terms as "a" or "of". On a site with many inputs and hosting "very" shared, it takes time to return results or gives error.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Set minimum number of characters in the search](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/56279/set-minimum-number-of-characters-in-the-search)

Comment: @Michael Stop words and word length are different topics.

Comment: @toscho Sure, however the central problem is how to influence the search to deal with these words, which brings it (in my personal opinion) basically back to one topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this in your `functions.php`, and change `news` for whatever you want to be blocked in your site.

```
add_action('wp', 'check_search');
function check_search() {

    global $wp_query;

    if (!$s = get_search_query())
        return false;

    if (preg_match('/news/', $s)) {
        $wp_query->set_404();
        status_header(404);
        get_template_part(404);
        exit();
    }

}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi @Vinicius Massuchetto ...('/news/', $s)) unfortunately it did not work. site.com/?s=news usually is returning results.

Comment: I'm sorry. Try again with the new snippet. =D

Comment: What a pity @Vinicius Massuchetto - Oops! Fatal error: Call to a member function set_404()... What should be happening?

Comment: I can't believe! While pasting the new snippet I forgot the `global $wp_query` line. With that you should have your functionality running.

Comment: Oh, yes @Massuchetto Vinicius, `global $wp_query` was missing. Thank again.

Comment: @Massuchetto Vinicius I'm not able to add more words. But a word is functioning well... - Take what I said. Able to add more words:`if (preg_match('/of/', $s) || preg_match('/a/', $s))`

Comment: @MichaelWilliam you can add more words in one regex doing like `preg_match('/^(word1|word2|word3)$/', $s)`